# Crowdsale end time

Tags: solidity, crowdsale, openzeppelin

Question about setting crowdsale end time. Is it possible to have an adjustable end time? Meaning there's no end time set, and admin can end the crowdsale any time once the crowdsale started.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. If you run into trouble while implementing it, please feel free to ask a specific question with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a transaction that set a variable to a specific value, nothing special:

```
uint endTime;
address admin;

modifier isAdmin() {
    require(msg.sender == admin);
    _;
}

function setEndTime(uint timestamp) public isAdmin returns (bool) {
    // Do check stuff you want
    endTime = timestamp;
    return true;
}
```